# vb.net, sql server, datetime format, select

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datetime, format, max

I am using vb.net to load data from SQL Server. I have table for inks and I have another table for tracking the employees been consuming these inks. I have VB.NET form with Datetimepicker control. The date time in SQL server is saved in the format `yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.000` and the format in Datetimepicker is `yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.000`. When I load the data from the SQL server to my Datagrid in VB.NET I do not get the right data. Would someone please make clear about the Datetime format so I get the right data?
Thanks

Comment: Is the column in Sql Server a DateTime column or varchar or something else?

Comment: hi, the column is datetime datatype. what exactly i want to do? I want to display the status of the inks at a particular date. I have the INK table and the INK_STOCK table where every time an employee request an ink i add that record in it. the sql statement i use gets the maximum date for each INK modification and i get them right. but  when i specify i want the ink status to be at a particular date selected from datetimepicker, idont get the right results or no results at all

Comment: inkId    smallint Unchecked
type    varchar(10) Unchecked
pBrandId   smallint Unchecked
code    varchar(35) Unchecked
color    varchar(15) Checked
description varchar(50) Checked
  Unchecked


recordId int Unchecked
inkId        smallint Unchecked
dat        datetime Unchecked
onHand        smallint Unchecked
receipts smallint Unchecked
used        smallint Unchecked
  Unchecked

Comment: or can someone tell me a better database structure to keep track in these inks consume?